# Using user-defined literals in expressions sometimes requires whitespace

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

The following code compiles in both GCC and Clang:

```
long double operator""_a(long double);     
auto x = 0e1_a+0; // OK
```

But not this (replacing `_a` with `_e`):

```
long double operator""_e(long double);
auto y = 0e1_e+0; // Error: unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""_e+0'
```

OTOH, this code compiles:

```
auto z = 0e1_e +0; // OK
```

What's going on?

(This question is inspired by [this GCC bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68288).)

Answer (score 14):

Maximal munch strikes again.

[lex.pptoken]/p3:

> If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a
>   given character:
>
> - [two exceptions not relevant here]
> - Otherwise, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token, even if that
>     would cause further lexical analysis to fail, except that a
>     *header-name* (2.8) is only formed within a `#include` directive (16.2).

The problem is that `0e1_e+0`, unlike `0e1_a+0`, is a valid preprocessing number ([lex.ppnumber]):

```
pp-number:
    digit
    . digit
    pp-number digit
    pp-number identifier-nondigit
    pp-number ’ digit
    pp-number ’ nondigit
    pp-number e sign
    pp-number E sign
    pp-number .
```

As a result, `0e1_e+0` is parsed as a single *pp-number* preprocessing token, and then explodes later because it cannot be converted to a valid token (for obvious reasons).

`0e1_a+0`, on the other hand, is parsed as three tokens, `0e1_a`, `+`, and `0`, and all is well.

Comment: So its happen for every name finishing by `e` or `E` :/